# Lenovo 100S wakes from sleep and drains battery

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, battery, uefi

I have a **Lenovo 100S-11IBY** laptop running **Windows 10**. It has UEFI (and not regular BIOS) and it only supports the new "Connected Standby" type of sleep (also called S0). It doesn't support any of the traditional sleep or hibernate modes. The Power Options are therefore severely limited and pretty much every device doesn't have a "Power Management" tab in the device properties.

If I put the laptop to sleep, it would remain in sleep (and preserve battery) for some time, but then it would randomly wake up and drain the battery. If the laptop happens to be in my backpack it can get rather hot. The only option when the battery reaches a low level is to shut down (there is no sleep or hibernate), so everything I had open would just be force closed and Windows would shut down at 1% battery. This has become really annoying and defeats the "long battery" claim - if I'm traveling and I left home with a fully charged sleeping laptop, I might end up with a drained or almost drained boiling hot laptop when I sit down at a coffee shop to use it.

I noticed that if I apply pressure on the laptop lid (but not in any specific spot) it would wake up as well. I am suspecting a key on the keyboard is getting pressed, because pulling open the laptop slightly and pressing a key with my fingers would also wake the laptop - and so would just tapping on the touchpad. This is really annoying because the laptop wakes up from the slightest disturbance - key, tap, mouse, or lid open... But ideally what I want (and what I used to do with an old laptop) is that nothing would wake the sleeping computer except the Power button. There are no Power Management options on the keyboard or mouse so there's no way to control its wake behavior.

Besides applying pressure, the laptop would also just wake up randomly even if it's left without any pressure whatsoever on a table or bench.

I have tried a registry trick to switch back to traditional sleep types (S1 through S4) but since the UEFI doesn't support any of these, I simply don't have any options to sleep or hibernate in this mode. Hence I switched again to the default "connected standby" type of sleep (it's the only way I can use Sleep).

[image: powercfg /a results]

I have checked the UEFI settings, but it's also very limited and doesn't have any power option whatsoever. (It seems like new technologies are dumbed down to a bare minimum customization settings and refuse to offer the much finer control that older technologies offered to geeks.)

Currently my only option to guarantee preserving battery is to always shut down. This is very inconvenient as I want to continue working without having to save, close and open the programs and documents again. This completely defeats the purpose of having a sleep feature.

**Is there any solution to this?**

You can view the diagnostic reports from powercfg [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ueg6WQMioKQmlQOWtGcW5OV2c) (click Download, extract and open the HTML files). I don't really understand these reports, but I see some unknown devices that are flagged red. (I don't have any external removable devices connected.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with UEFI vs BIOS, and more to do with what they chose to support on this particular model.

Comment: @MosheKatz Thanks for the clarification. Admittedly this is my first laptop with an UEFI :D